# Visually solving the integral of $\sin(x)$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, visualization

I just tried to visually solve the integral of $\sin(x)$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ by considering the unit circle.

I tried to sketch my idea. The link is below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-uFKRww3qhWRk5oVGRHRENVY28/view?usp=sharing

If one lays a Cartesian coordinate system with its origin coinciding with the center of the unit circle, then the y-coordinate can be thought of as representing the value of $\sin(x)$ at a given angle.

If I would add all the values from $2$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, this is to my understanding the same as visually drawing a line for each x by gradually taking a little step $dx$. This corresponds to my understanding of an integral as a Riemann sum.
The sum of all the "lines" is the area, namely $\frac{1}{4}$ of the unit circles area.
Ergo $\frac{1}{4}$.

As I found out analytically the integral is not $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Wherein lies my error?

I am very grateful for your help in advance!

Comment: The problem is that the little steps $dx$ are not happening on the horizontal axis. Since $x$ measures an angle, the $dx$ is a small change in angle. So the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin x \ dx$ does not correspond to the quarter circle you shaded. (The quarter circle corresponds to $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} \ dx$, which is in fact $\pi/4$.)

Comment: Oh thank you! Sometimes one is so obsessed with ones idea that one oversees the most obvious ideas.